# Как загрузить проект в гибХаб в новой ветке?

Tags: git, github, консоль, branch, commit

Следовал инструкциям одного видео и положил проект на ГитХаб, но теперь не получается положить этот же проект в новой ветке. После команды git add . - ничего не происхдит

Comment: Что значит "положить проект в другой ветке"? Можно более подробно, что хотите получить и что делали?

Comment: Если вы просто создали новую ветку `git checkout -b new_branch`, то `git add .` действительно ничего не добавит, потому что изменений в файлах не было. 
Чтобы отправить ветку в удалённый репозиторий нужно выполнить `git push origin new_branch`